# Etimología de "a pachas"

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, españa

[A pachas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ROwivtV) es una expresión usada para indicar una acción realizada entre 2 personas por igual.

Durante un viaje a Nepal me sorprendió que los locales entendieran el sentido de un comentario realizado entre hispanohablantes en el que se trataba de compartir ciertos gastos *a pachas* (a medias). Resulta que en nepalí, *pachas* significa 50, se pronuncia como en español y es habitual su uso como *fifty-fifty*.

Ahora la pregunta: ¿Cuál es la etimología de pachas en español?

Pienso que es improbable que la coincidencia con la palabra nepalí para indicar 50 sea mera casualidad. ¿O sí lo es?

Comment: +1 por la historia del idioma nepalí. ¡Cuanto menos es curiosa la coincidencia!

Comment: Supongo que la palabra nepalí viene de la raíz sánscrita *pañc* que significa *cinco*. De ahí viene la palabra *ponche* (a través del inglés *punch*, porque la receta original usada en la India llevaba cinco ingredientes) o el nombre de la región del Punjab (=*cinco ríos*). Así que podría venir de algún otro idioma de esa zona. Tal vez incluso del caló, fuente de muchas expresiones del argot de España.

Comment: Sobre la improabilidad que mencionas: hace años alguien me señalo la asombrosa coincidencia entre la palabra correspondiente a "pajaro" en vascuence (txori) y japonés (tori)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como dice Gorpik en su comentario, la expresión parece venir del habla gitana: el [*Diccionario de frases hechas y dichos*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UV23VTQe4PQC&pg=PT22#v=onepage&q&f=false) de Alberto Buitrago (2012) señala que

> La expresión tiene como origen el gitanismo *a pacha*, 'de acuerdo'.

El significado de esta última expresión lo confirma el [*Diccionario de argot español ó lenguaje jergal gitano, delincuente profesional y popular*](https://archive.org/stream/diccionariodearg00bessuoft#page/120/mode/2up) de Luis Besses (c. 1921):

> **Pacha** *pop. A pacha.* De acuerdo.

Queda por averiguar si, en efecto, ese gitanismo proviene de la raíz sánscrita indicada por Gorpik.

Comment: ¡Gran investigación, como siempre! Tienes muchos y muy variados recursos, JMVanPelt, si quieres añade alguno a [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Gracias! Mis recursos no son mucho más que Google, Google Books e Internet Archive, y el hecho de que me guste hurgar en los libros viejos que se encuentran ahí; por lo general, me entero de la existencia de las fuentes que cito cuando busco, en alguno de esos lugares, algo que preguntan aquí.